# How to "insert" guest additions image in VirtualBox from command line, while VM is running?

Tags: command-line, virtualbox

I have my VMs on a dedicated computer, over SSH I use `vboxheadless` to start them, and then I use remote desktop to use them.

Now, while a VM is running, it is trivial to insert the "GuestAdditions" image into the guest's optical drive and install them. To do that with an attached GUI, it's at <kbd>Devices</kbd> > <kbd>Insert Guest Additions CD Image</kbd>.

However, I'm not using the GUI because I'm using the guest OS via remote desktop, so I obviously don't have the menus, either.

I'd like to know how to perform this function from command line. I'd imagine it's using `vboxmanage` to insert and remove that CD image from the virtual guest machine's drive.

Also, is there a way how to insert any other CD images and/or floppy images into the virtual drives of a guest system - and remove them - while the guest OS is running?

Comment: Check http://superuser.com/questions/741734/virtualbox-how-can-i-add-mount-a-iso-image-file-from-command-line

Comment: @StephenHarris thanks. Helps with attaching arbitrary ISO images, but not how to attach guest additions and floppy images.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The way I do this is:

#### Get the VboxAdditions UUID

```
[fredmj@Lagrange ~]$ vboxmanage list dvds
[...]
UUID:           3cc8e4fb-e56e-blabla...
State:          created
Type:           readonly
Location:       /usr/share/virtualbox/VBoxGuestAdditions.iso
Storage format: RAW
Capacity:       55 MBytes
Encryption:     disabled
```

#### Use `vboxmanage storageattach` with the correct UUID

to grab the UUID and put it in the `vboxmanage` command:

```
[fredmj@Lagrange ~]$ vboxmanage storageattach CENTOS7.GUESTADD --storagectl SATA --port 1 --type dvddrive --medium 3cc8e4fb-e56e-blabla..
```

Reading the [User Manual](https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/UserManual.html), I thought it was possible to use something like `--medium additions`, but I didn't figure how.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Two comments: (a) Check first with vboxmanage showvminfo $vmname that you don't have a disk already attached on port 1 of the SATA controller and (b) storageattach requires the VM to be shut down.

Comment: I ended up downloading the iso once again and attaching it using the tips from here: https://superuser.com/questions/741734/virtualbox-how-can-i-add-mount-a-iso-image-file-from-command-line

Comment: Running `vboxmanage list dvds` does not show the guest additions iso for me, even though its's in `/usr/share/virtualbox`.

Answer (score 1):

For anyone else that comes across this question, the `--medium additions` seems to require the dvddrive to already exist (I was trying to create it and attach the additions in one step). To add a dvddrive and attach the additions, this works:

```
VBoxManage storageattach test --storagectl "SATA" --port 1 --type dvddrive --medium emptydrive
VBoxManage storageattach test --storagectl "SATA" --port 1 --type dvddrive --medium additions
```

Answer (score 0):

**To mount the Guest Additions iso:**

`VBoxManage storageattach <VM name> --storagectl "IDE Controller" --port 1 --device 0 --type dvddrive --medium additions`

**To "unmount" the iso image:**

`VBoxManage storageattach <VM name> --storagectl "IDE Controller" --port 1 --device 0 --type dvddrive --medium emptydrive`

---

The above is based on `"IDE Controller"`, port `1`, device `0`. Adjust as necessary.

To get the values for `--storagectl`, `--port` and `--device`:

`VBoxManage showvminfo <VM name> --machinereadable | grep IsEjected`

An output like `"IDE Controller-IsEjected-1-0"="off"` would mean `"IDE Controller"`, port `1`, device `0`.

---

To check that `VBoxGuestAdditions.iso` is available in the system:

`VBoxManage list dvds`